# Dates in Excel 2013 Pivot Tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I am collecting daily KPI data but my baseline data was reported monthly.  I have 30 departments and 5 KPIs.  I set up my raw data collection tool in Excel and plan to pivot the data.

Can my baseline data be listed in the date column as 11/2015 and my daily data formatted as 12/12/15, 12/13/15 etc in the same column?  I want to be able to compare daily data to baseline.

Or other ideas?

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail? How do you expect to format the same column with two different number formats? Is there a field that indicates which is "baseline" and which is "daily" data?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to accomplish this by making the date fields text rather than dates.  The input column in the Pivot Table source will need to be Text.

If you make the monthly baseline a date of 11/2015 it should sort to the top.  Be careful to use 2-digit days because 12/11/2015 will sort before 12/7/2015 when stored as text.

This is assuming you will have the dates as rows and the KPIs as columns.